# Execute EJB's method with a timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timeout, ejb-3.0

I would like to develop a certain method of an EJB, having a timeout for the execution (passed togheter with the method's parameters), without using transactions.

**How would you do that?**

Comment: What do you want to happen when the timeout occurs? What do you mean by "without using transactions"? Do you just want the method to run without transactions (aka, NEVER transaction policy), or is that comment somehow related to timeout?

Comment: An exception is thrown . I want the transactions to be authomatically managed

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking, but I can say there is no way to automatically timeout an EJB method. The best you can do is have the method itself periodically check if it has been running for too long and then throw an exception.

Comment: Ive checked out the "Timing Service" , you know if I can adapt that to my case?

Comment: No, the TimerService just allows you to schedule things to happen in the future. You cannot use it to interrupt/cancel an in-progress method.